# What is the correct way to write "To all who handles" or "To all whom handles"?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way to write "To all who handles" or "To all whom handles" or "To all who is handling" ?

Comment: Please show the complete sentence.

Comment: None of the options you give is correct: _all_ is plural and requires that the verb in the following clause be plural too. _To all (those) who handle X_ and _To all (those) who are handling X_ are both grammatically correct, but they would be used in different contexts; so as mplungjan says, please edit your question to indicate in what context the phrase is to be used.

Comment: Simple rule for English learners: Don't use _whom_. Ever. It will take you years to learn how it's sposta be used, and even if you use it correctly, so many English speakers use it incorrectly that they will consider you wrong. There's no way to win.

Comment: ... The bell tolls for 'whom'.

Comment: You need to post a complete sentence. But when in doubt stick with "who". It's better to use "who" and get it wrong than to use "whom" and get it wrong, because the latter is likely to attract more ridicule.

Comment: A handy rule of thumb (I AM joking, of course) is that if you would use the Nominative in Latin, use "who", otherwise use "whom". Please don't use this in real life though, and just use "who", as everyone else has said. :-)

Answer (score 2):

All are incorrect. As you do not give the context, I will add one.
“Give the warning to all who handle the chemical.”
“Give the warning to him who handles the chemical.”
“To him who handles the chemical, I would give the following warning…”
“To all who are handling the chemical, I would give the following warning…”
The confusion between “who” and “whom” may be coming from two directions. Following “to,” you expect to use “him, us, them, whom,” etc. As the subject of the verb “to handle,” however, you expect to use “he, we, they, who,” etc. It may be helpful to think of “who handles the chemical” as an entity: Someone handles the chemical; it is “he handles,” not “him handles.”

Answer (score 0):

"to all who handle" is correct (not one of your choices).

Confusion is:

to all (who handle)
vs.
to whom

"who handle" modifies all. The use of whom is obviated by the use of all. "handle" is the correct form of the verb.

The comments or responses which say to avoid "whom" are really contributing to ignorance rather than insight. Sadly that is common these days.